# Sending specific keys when using Remote Desktop UNIX commands

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, server.app, unix, apple-remote-desktop

I would like to script the uninstallation and reinstallation of Profiles on a group of Networked Macs. In order to do this I shall use the UNIX Command part of Remote Desktop.

When sending the

```
profiles -D
```

Command, it responds with

```
Are you sure you want to delete all configuration profiles? [y/n]:
```

but I have no way of pressing the Y key.

Any ideas?

Comment: Guesswork, hence comment not answer, but what other parameters other than `-D` can you send? Is there a `-Y` for example?

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but it seems -f does the trick!

Comment: You can pipe yes to the command as well... => `$ yes | profiles -D`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the `profiles` [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/profiles.1.html), the `-f` flag will:

*Automatically confirm any questions, or when used with -s, will retry startup profiles at each startup until successfully installed.*

So, my guess is `profiles -Df` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that myself! Thanks